# DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, mysql, spring, reactjs

I am working on Spring Boot in server and react in frontend with the MySQL.

When I am launching my application, I am getting the below error.

Any pointers for this issue ?

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Process finished with exit code 1

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.alexisvachard</groupId>
    <artifactId>authentication-poc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>authentication-poc</name>
    <description>JWT Authentication poc</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <swagger-ui.version>2.9.2</swagger-ui.version>
        <aerogear-otp-java.version>1.0.0</aerogear-otp-java.version>
        <zxing-core.version>3.3.3</zxing-core.version>
        <zxing-javase.version>3.3.3</zxing-javase.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.warrenstrange</groupId>
            <artifactId>googleauth</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${zxing-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>${zxing-javase.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application-dev.properties

```
#-Dspring.profiles.active=dev

### SERVER PROPERTIES
server.address=localhost
server.port=8080

### SPRING DATASOURCE PROPERTIES
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

### HIBERNATE PROPERTIES
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

### JACKSON PROPERTIES
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
spring.jackson.date-format=dd-MM-yyyy

### LOG PROPERTIES
logging.level.fr.alexisvachard.authenticationpoc=TRACE
logging.file=authentication-poc.log

### APPLICATION PROPERTIES
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.app.front.host=http://localhost:3000

fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.jwt.secret=
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.jwt.expirationInMs=604800000
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.jwt.rememberMeExpirationInMs=2592000000

fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.cors.maxAge=3600

fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.email.from=
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.email.template-base-package=/mailTemplate

### EMAIL PROPERTIES
spring.mail.host=
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.port=

## ACTUATOR SETTINGS
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.httptrace.enabled=true
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/manage

management.endpoint.health.roles=ROLE_ADMIN
management.endpoint.health.show-details=when_authorized

management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=*
management.endpoints.web.cors.max-age=3600s
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-headers=*
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, httptrace, metrics
```

application-prod.properties

```
#-Dspring.profiles.active=prod

### SERVER PROPERTIES
server.address=localhost
server.port=8080

### SPRING DATASOURCE PROPERTIES
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

### HIBERNATE PROPERTIES
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

### JACKSON PROPERTIES
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
spring.jackson.date-format=dd-MM-yyyy

### LOG PROPERTIES
logging.level.fr.alexisvachard.authenticationpoc=TRACE
logging.file=authentication-poc.log

### APPLICATION PROPERTIES
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.app.front.host=http://localhost:3000

fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.jwt.secret=
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.jwt.expirationInMs=604800000
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.jwt.rememberMeExpirationInMs=2592000000

fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.cors.maxAge=3600

fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.email.from=
fr.alexisvachard.authentication-poc.email.template-base-package=/mailTemplate

### EMAIL PROPERTIES
spring.mail.host=
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.port=

## ACTUATOR SETTINGS
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.httptrace.enabled=true
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/manage

management.endpoint.health.roles=ROLE_ADMIN
management.endpoint.health.show-details=when_authorized

management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=*
management.endpoints.web.cors.max-age=3600s
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-headers=*
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, httptrace, metrics
```

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to run the application?

I noticed you have two profiles: dev and prod.

If you run the app with no profile, Spring Boot you "look" for default, and it seems you do not have default properties file.

More infos: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles